# Why do I need a client id for OAuth2 password grant flow?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, passwords, authorization, clientid

Example:

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: authorization-server.com
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password
&username=exampleuser
&password=1234luggage
&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx
```

Why do I need a client id for OAuth2 password grant flow? Why is  username and password not enough?

Answer (score 3):

The token endpoint will issue an access token. The access token denotes "Who grants what permissions to whom."

- ***Who*** here is the user who is identified by `username`.
- ***what permissions*** here are scopes listed in a `scope` request parameter (although your example does not include the `scope` request parameter).
- ***whom*** here is a client application.

For the authorization server to know ***whom*** (i.e. a client application), you need to include a `client_id` request parameter.

Comment: In other words: The login page usually shows the name of the application in the login dialog, so the user knows for whom (s)he allows access, this name it can get by the `client_id`. And it does only allow access for apps which are registered by the developer, so it knows which privileges are required by this app and which are not.